# Updating QWidget style after setting it readonly

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtstylesheets

I have Qt style sheet (`qss`) for `QLineEdit`, using different styles for readonly and editable. Works fine, but if I toggle a `QLineEdit` to readonly (at runtime) the style does not change.

Is there a way to force a stylesheet update of such a line edit?

As requested, the stylesheet:

```
QLineEdit {
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

QLineEdit[readOnly="true"] {
  background: rgba(40,40,40);
  border: 1px solid rgba(50,50,50);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here my own findings:

- The `polish` / `unpolish` thing works
- However, it is somehow inconvenient as I have to apply it for each `QLineEdit` object, it does not work for me if I do it on the parent level (e.g. on a dialog with multiple `QLineEdit`s)

What works for me is to force an update like this
`widget->setStyleSheet(widget->styleSheet());`, by just setting the same stylesheet. I works also on the top level widget, updating multiple child elements.

Answer (score 3):

After change edit's state try next code:

```
qApp->style()->unpolish(this);
qApp->style()->polish(this);
```

Where "this" current QMainWindow or QDialog.

Comment: Just `widget->polish(); widget->unpolish();`. **Polish should be first**.

Comment: It works. But behavior is heavy dependend on platform.

Comment: According to the Qt wiki, it is `unpolish` first. But you don't need to run that on the whole window, only on modified widgets.

Comment: For me it does not work on "parent" level, only if I do it on the `QLineEdit`itself, see my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48321977/356726